# How to create Regular expression to extract a value from the string response?

Tags: jmeter

How to find the regular expression to extract the Value Tag from the following response?

```
<CustomFieldList>
    <CustomField>
        <Name>OFFER_META_DATA</Name>
        <Value>
            SE7gOMOEOfvKjka8b+8k4SqccKEAB8ZjUqDl0Mv7OZeKEITd0l2rAFAL1XAxgzE8+lLt6XaR9IYDY0MmUaRfGXkiE/SOmYzMB+DccN2V1cOfsBav1BNaUsubTKW79qtXwwNcg4saeZZSqaiAVDJIFFUZq+u0UhqE6aZ2EbdwELyHZPP9HfHSRHCV9ihjlHvGHKRYdL2j4PvE5O5eg3ajmSTmI5aRAG42+epkCroTRDglUmCnHMTlA3VvSvtBV/fq9lI54JqqkSDj+83tKhclvZWPw08zu6drpp6PeZwmG1UwlmokLAwI0QCxYjnJEYwt7Ikt1sm8JqWzUPoVGHJoyw==%~~`%~~~~~~~%^**(%$#%ZWZby8uQ7CCjcQDbU7exlCDAXUeQ47bkD2kcxkobEQ9y1IBlPDpk7JEquCdxOnkKCRi9y8AswLegW98YyC+OAUoMCvN5XWYMJOmGK2gkj+5xzUbGZy9GS7ov4DQ+rPaHqvomADIKxXNw52ZSda/cwvfcUETGxi6yDcEgdIXj4abWQTNUGoSE34oHPNZ0CamHd1ZCZr36DqrIRXO595aTTAQX2E/ZUvoXnxT79ezoCOkt/xGOAEGKUjCUYYGnOAmHARf5t4aqK9Z+JhB8wVtT9KaD7xunGePjINmQrEYDeosEGrFyQ0OQWfwDyjQmA+GFbFRoabZgg3tkjCNCWEXI6Q==
        </Value>
    </CustomField>
</CustomFieldList>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS selector as shown below:-
[image]
[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use multi select regular expression. Please find below the required expression for your case

```
(?ms)<Value>(.*?)</Value>
```